# Tipo de dato ingresado en C#

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos

Intento crear un programa que al ingresar una entrada se pueda saber el tipo de dato que se ingreso como doble, flotante o string y se muestre que tipo de dato ingreso
El problema es que intenté con un metodo tryparse pero se queda con la primera condición que cumpla y eso impide saber si es doble o flotante; no hay problema en string o entero el problema son esos dos

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor muestra el código.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Primero debes poner el tryparse del float y luego el del double

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que lo que quieres es algo así:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escribe un dato y te digo su tipo:");
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (float.TryParse(s, out var _))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Es un float");
    }
    else if (double.TryParse(s, out var _))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Es un double");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Es un string");
    }
}
```

Pero realmente esto no es correcto, lo que se introduce por la consola nunca es un `float` o un `double`, siempre es un string. La cuestión es si ese `string` se puede convertir, "parsear" o puede ser una representación textual de un `float`o un `double`.

Por otra parte, toda representación textual de un `float` también es una representación textual de un `double`, igual que toda representación textual de un `int` lo es de un `long`. Y por supuesto de un `string`

El siguiente código te muestra si el texto introducido por consola es alguno de los tipos más comunes:

```
public record TypeVerifier(Type Type, Func<string, bool> CanBeParsed);
    
internal class Program
{
    static List<TypeVerifier> verifiers = new List<TypeVerifier>
    {
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(bool), s => bool.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(byte), s => byte.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(sbyte), s => sbyte.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(ushort), s => ushort.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(short), s => short.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(uint), s => uint.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(int), s => int.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(ulong), s => ulong.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(long), s => long.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(float), s => float.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(double), s => double.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(Guid), s => Guid.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(DateTime), s => DateTime.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(DateOnly), s => DateOnly.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(TimeOnly), s => TimeOnly.TryParse(s, out var _)),
        new TypeVerifier(typeof(TimeSpan), s => TimeSpan.TryParse(s, out var _)),
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe un dato y te digo los tipos:");
        var s = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (var v in verifiers)
        {
            if (v.CanBeParsed(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Type.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```